# Pointer and array usage confusion

Tags: c

There is a code excerpt from official [Quake 2 source code](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-2/blob/master/qcommon/cmodel.c):

```
unsigned        *buf;
dheader_t       header;
...
header = *(dheader_t *)buf; // #1
    for (i=0 ; i<sizeof(dheader_t)/4 ; i++)
        ((int *)&header)[i] = LittleLong ( ((int *)&header)[i]); // #2
```

Can someone please explain me in the most possible details what do the line #1 and then #2 really do because I'm little or more confused...

P.S

Here is the rest of the definitions if it helps:

```
int     LittleLong (int l) {return _LittleLong(l);}
...
typedef struct
{
    int         ident;
    int         version;    
    lump_t      lumps[HEADER_LUMPS];
} dheader_t;
```

P.S. 2

I've linked above the original full source file code if needed.

Comment: From what I recall, the various Quake (and therefore also Minecraft) code bases are known to use dirty hacks all over. Most of the code here is wildly undefined behavior.

Comment: Work from the inside out with expressions such as these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is some seriously brittle code and you shouldn't write code like this.

What it does is to go through the struct `int` by `int`, then does something with each such `int` inside `_LittleLong`. Very likely this function performs a 32 bit conversion from a big endian integer to a little endian one. Meaning that the source you are looking at is likely something related to reception of IP packages.

Checking at what the code does step by step:

- `for (i=0 ; i<sizeof(dheader_t)/4 ; i++)` is a sloppier way of writing `sizeof(dheader_t)/sizeof(int)`. That is: iterate through the struct `int` by `int`, chunks of 32 bits.
- `(int *)&header` converts from a `dheader_t*` to a `int*`. This is actually well-defined by a special rule in C that allows us to convert from a pointer to a struct to a pointer to its first member or vice versa and the first member is `int`.
- *However*, doing so is only well-defined for the first member. Instead they take the converted `int*` and apply array dereferencing on it: `((int *)&header)[i]`. This is undefined behavior in C, a so-called strict aliasing violation, and could also cause alignment problems in some situations. Bad.
- The `int` read from the struct through this dereferencing is then passed along to `LittleLong` which very likely does a big -> little endian conversion.
- `((int *)&header)[i] =`  and here it is written back to where it was grabbed from.

---

Better, safer, well-defined and possibly faster code could look like:

```
void endianify (dheader_t* header)
{
  _Static_assert(sizeof(dheader_t)%sizeof(uint32_t)==0,
                 "Broken struct: dheader_t");

  unsigned char* start = (unsigned char*)header;
  unsigned char* end   = start + sizeof(dheader_t);
  
  for(unsigned char* i=start; i!=end; i+=sizeof(uint32_t))
  {
    uint32_t tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp,i,sizeof(uint32_t));
    i[0]= (tmp >> 24) & 0xFF;
    i[1]= (tmp >> 16) & 0xFF;
    i[2]= (tmp >>  8) & 0xFF;
    i[3]= (tmp >>  0) & 0xFF;
  }
}
```

Disassembly:

```
endianify:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
    bswap   eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+4]
    bswap   eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+4], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+8]
    bswap   eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+8], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+12]
    bswap   eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+12], eax
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+16]
    bswap   eax
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+16], eax
    ret
```

Comment: So the construct `(int *)&header)[i] ` says: take the adders to the `header` structure and treat it as the pointer to an `i`-sized array of `int`'s?

Comment: @darro911 Yes, pretty much.